# PM2 and tsnode : pass "--fast" option

Tags: node.js, pm2, ts-node

I'm using pm2 (2.5.0) and ts-node (3.1.0)
I saw in ts-node's documentation that you can pass a "--fast" option, so that compilation is faster.

I'm using pm2 to start my .ts app. How can I tell pm2 to pass that 'fast' option to ts-node?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question ? I'm also interested

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found a solution

Comment: Note that as of [ts-node v4.0.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0), fast mode is on by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/13), the standard UNIX way of passing parameters to the script is supported since end of 2016. This should work:

```
pm2 start app.ts -- -F
```